# v-date-picker is not popping up in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

[v-date-picker is not popping up which is inside the v-menu. Please help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffYNF.png)

```
<v-menu v-model="menu1" :close-on-content-click="false" full-width max-width="290">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-text-field :value="computedDateFormattedMomentjs" clearable label="Formatted with Moment.js"
            readonly v-on="on"></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker v-model="date" @change="menu1 = false"></v-date-picker>
</v-menu>

<v-menu v-model="menu2" :close-on-content-click="false" full-width max-width="290">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-text-field :value="computedDateFormattedDatefns" clearable label="Formatted with datefns"
            readonly v-on="on"></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker v-model="date" @change="menu2 = false"></v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

> date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
> computedDateFormattedMomentjs() {
> return this.date ? moment(this.date).format('MMMM Do yyyy') : ''
> },

Comment: The tags say you are using Vue/Vuetify 3, but the code is for v2 (there is no `on` slot prop in v3).